# Facebook get members posts in an App and Game group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group, facebook-game-groups

Is there a way to get members posts in App and Game groups?

Because when I use **/%group-id%/feed** in Graph API (using App Token Access) it only returns posts of the App. But when I open the group's page in Facebook I can see all posts of members of the group.

It seems to be normal because I found that in the documentation

> When games post stories as the game, the stories will look like they were posted from the app. Games can view the likes and comments on its posts by reading the feed.
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/game-groups/v2.2#design

So, does anybody know if it is possible for a Facebook App to get posts of users inside its groups?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like they limited this deliberately to the post made by the app, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group/feed says, _“an app access token can read posts it published in app and game groups that belong to it”_ – so you might need to use a user access token to get the full group feed.

Comment: I also tried with a user access token but it still returns only posts that the app published.

Comment: Then you should maybe [file a bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs) – I don’t think this is intentional, there should be a way to get the full feed for App&Game Groups as well.

Comment: What is the nature of the group's privacy setting? Is it OPEN or CLOSED? Did you check 
_A user access token, for a member of the group, with **user_groups** permission_

Comment: Hi Nithya,
I'm user a token with these scopes : user_groups, user_managed_groups, user_friends, user_posts, read_stream, publish_actions, public_profile
and it's a CLOSED group. Of course, the user for the token is member of the group ;-)
I opened a bug report on Facebook, we are investigating...